# How to fix gunicorn.service: Failed to load environment

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, systemd

When i run

```
sudo journalctl -u gunicorn
```

I get:

```
Oct 14 12:49:22 django-ubuntu-helpme systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed to load environment >
Oct 14 12:49:22 django-ubuntu-helpme  systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed to run 'start' task:>
Oct 14 12:49:22 django-ubuntu-helpme  systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'resourc>
Oct 14 12:49:22 django-ubuntu-helpme  systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

I suppose something doesn’t add up with my directories. I have

`/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` which is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myname
Group=myname
EnvironmentFile=/home/myname/myapp/env
WorkingDirectory=/home/myname/myapp
ExecStart=/home/myname/myapp/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The directories I’m working in are as follows.

`myapp/` has my `requirements.txt` file, `env/`, and another `app/` dir. Within `myapp/app`, I have `manage.py`, an env file that containt my SECRET_KEY which I've exported, and another `app/` dir. Within `myapp/app/app,` I have `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EnvironmentFile should be a text file instead of a directory. Please go through:  https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Comment: @VidyaSagar well spotted, thanks!!